# camera_pose_calibration image format error

Tags: ros, openni, xtion, camera-pose-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to use camera_pose_calibration to calibrate my Asus Xtion depth camera to a RGB camera. I calibrated both cameras and the launch file, except for this warning

"[ WARN] [1346835528.616595129]: You've passed in true for auto_start for the C++ action server at [/tf2_buffer_server]. You should always pass in false to avoid race conditions."

starts everything normally. But when I try to start calibrate_2_camera.launch, I get the following error:

"Creating aggregator for ['/gscam', '/camera/rgb']

ERROR [1346837613.386631463]: Unable to convert '8UC3' image to bgr8: 'Unsupported conversion from [8UC3] to [bgr8]'  "

Which keeps repeating periodically. This happens both with the built in RGB camera (for that I use a bag file) and an external RGB camera. The version of camera_pose_calibration that I'm using comes from [here](https://bitbucket.org/jbohren/camera_pose).

Does anyone know what's causing this and/or how to solve it?
Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44535/camera_pose_calibration-image-format-error/) by [Pedro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3142/pedro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 102 on 2012-09-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-09-25**:
What's the output of 'rostopic echo /camera/rgb/encoding' ?

**Comment by [Pedro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3142/pedro/) on 2012-09-27**:
From Asus Xtion, /camera/rgb/image_rect encoding is mono8.

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-09-27**:
That's confusing! So if /camera/rgb/image_rect is a mono image, is there something wrong with the openni pipeline with the Xtion?

**Comment by [Pedro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3142/pedro/) on 2012-09-27**:
image_rect is published by image_proc and it's supposed to be mono. image_rect_color is bgr8, but the tutorial about extrinsic calibration in openni_launch says to use image_rect.

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-09-28**:
Ah right. So have you tried it with image_rect_color?

**Comment by [Pedro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3142/pedro/) on 2012-10-02**:
I did and the same happened. Anyway, with the last ROS update it's finally working (with image_rect). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

it is a bug as the behavior got broken but it is still doing the right thing: 8UC3 just tells you your image has 3 channels that are uint8. There is absolutely no color information in there: it could be RGB, BGR, YUV .... It therefore does not make sense to convert it to a color coded format.

Then again, 1.8.5 restores that behavior (it assumes 8UC3 is RGB). Groovy will throw that message again (but camera_pose_calibration will be fixed then).

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2012-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-09-26**:
Vincent, are you resurrecting camera_pose_calibration?

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2014-01-06**:
From these comments it seems like this problem was supposed to be fixed but I'm still getting the same errors trying to use the camera_pose_calibration right now.  Is there a more updated package for multiple Kinect calibration that you know of?  Or can this be used with Hydro?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a bug in the new cv_bridge API. It should be fixed in the next release, 1.8.5, which will be available in deb packages in the next few days.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-09-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5